# Google Spreadsheet month,year aggregation stops at november

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I use this query in Google Spreadsheets to aggregate certain tasks for every month of the year. However, the aggregation stops after month 10 (i.e. November and December are not parsed as the result). Any thoughts on where I'm screwing up?

```
=QUERY('Task Registration'!A:Z;"select month(A),year(A),sum(C),sum(D),sum(E),sum(F),sum(V),sum(W),sum(X),sum(Y),sum(Z),(sum(V)-sum(W)) where A is not null group by month(A),year(A)";2)
```

Data looks like this. The spreadsheet has 2 header rows.

```
31-10-2014,stef,8,15,12,1,3,4,1,5,4,1,
```

Answer (score 0):

Stef.
Don't know if this gonna help, but when month is used in QUERY the 'numbering' is shifted. I mean: dates in january are returned (by the month function) as zero, december is returned as '11'.
That's why I always use month(A)+1..